# Should I convert my dummy variables to factors?

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I'm using dummy variables in a panel regression with the package plm. I've noticed, however, that my entire dataset consists of numeric vectors, including the dummy vector (which consists of two values: 1 and 0). I was including both the dummy and interaction effects with the dummy in the plm regression in this way:

```r
model <- plm (GDP ~ G + dummy + I(G*dummy))
```

When I noticed that my dummy variable was a numeric one, I converted it  to a factor and ran the regression again, what yielded the same results:

```r
panel$dummy <- as.factor(panel$dummy)
levels(panel$dummy) <- c(0,1)
model <- plm (GDP ~ G + dummy + G:dummy)
```

As my entire analysis was done using dummy as a numeric vector and with the interaction I(G*dummy), I'm afraid this can have unintended consequences. Does it make any difference at all? Should I convert to factor and remake my entire script?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If it yields the same result in the panel regression, you can leave it that way. I don't know what you mean with unintended side effects in your script. What are you doing in your script?

Comment: Thanks! I don't know. After the last errors in my data (for example, loading dplyr disables plm::lag) I'm being very careful with everything hahahha, so I was  afraid that both approaches, although yielding similar results, could have a subtle difference.

Comment: Do they now yield similar or the same results? o.O In your question you say "the same", while now you say "similar". o.O

Comment: No, the same results hahahah poor choice of words